# Likelihood Ratio Test: Uniform Distribution, Change of Inequality in Alternative Hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Thanks, in advance. I would really appreciate any help here.

---

Problem:  Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from a $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,\theta)$ population.  Let $$H_0 : \theta = \theta_0 \quad \text{and} \quad H_A : \theta < \theta_0.$$  The unrestricted MLE of $\theta$ is $X_{(n)}$ (the maximum).

**(a)** Show that for a likelihood ratio test of size $\alpha$ that the rejection region is $$\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta_0} < \alpha^{1/n}.$$

**Solution**:  This question I was able to do.  We know that the rejection region for any GLRT is of the form $$RR = \{\Lambda(X_1, \ldots, X_n) < c\}.$$  So, $$\begin{align*}
\Pr[\text{reject } H_0 \mid H_0 \text{ true}] &= \Pr[\Lambda(X_1, \ldots, X_n) < c \mid \theta = \theta_0] \\
&= \Pr[(X_{(n)}/\theta_0)^n < c \mid \theta = \theta_0 ] \\
&= \Pr[X_{(n)} < c^{1/n} \theta_0 \mid \theta = \theta_0 ] \\
&= \Pr[X_1 < c^{1/n} \theta_0 \mid \theta = \theta_0]^n \\
&= \biggl( \int_{x=0}^{c^{1/n} \theta_0} \frac{1}{\theta_0} \, dx \biggr)^{\! n} \\
&= (c^{1/n})^n = c \\
&= \alpha \end{align*}$$
Thus, $$RR = \{\Lambda(X_1, \ldots, X_n) < c\} = \left\{ \left(\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta_0}\right)^{\! n} < \alpha \right\} = \left\{ \frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta_0} < \alpha^{1/n} \right\}.$$

**(b)** Now, let $$H_0 : \theta = \theta_0 \quad \text{and} \quad H_A : \theta > \theta_0.$$  Show that the LRT is simple in the sense that if $X_{(n)} < \theta_0$ we accept $H_0$ and if $X_{(n)} > \theta_0$ we reject $H_0$ for all $\alpha$.

**Attempt at this question**:  So in this case would the rejection region of the LRT switch to this:  $$RR = \{ \Lambda(X_1, \ldots, X_n) > c \}?$$  My reasoning is that if $\Lambda(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = (X_{(n)}/\theta_0)^n$, then $H_A$ implies that $\theta > \theta_0 = X_{(n)} > \theta_0$ and so we would expect $(X_{(n)}/\theta_0)^n$ to be a number larger than one if $H_A$ is true.  And so, doing the same process as **(a)** for all $\alpha$ it would follow that if $X_{(n)}/\theta_0 > 1$ (as long as $X_{(n)} > \theta_0$) then we would always reject for all $\alpha$ since we end up with $(X_{(n)}/\theta_0)^n > \alpha \rightarrow X_{(n)}/\theta_0 > \alpha^{1/n}$ and $0 < \alpha \le 1$.  Of course, the bound could be lower for different $\alpha$ that aren't one, but $X_{(n)}/\theta_0 > 1$ will always be a stronger condition.

Basically, this whole idea revolves around the RR being different from what I am used to seeing.  What is wrong with my reasoning?

**EDIT:** I believe I have figured out this problem. Here was my solution in case anyone cares:

Since $\Lambda_r = (\frac {X_{(n)}}{\theta_0})^n$ , we know that if $H_A : \theta > \theta_0$ then this implies that $H_A : X_{(n)} > \theta_0$. So, we want to find c such that again,

$Pr[reject \ H_0 | H_0 \ is \ true]
=Pr[\Lambda_r < c \ \ | \theta = \theta_0]$=$Pr[\ (\frac {X_{(n)}}{\theta_0})^n < c \ \ | \ \ \theta = \theta_0] = \alpha$.

If indeed $H_A : X_{(n)} > \theta_0$ is true then this would imply (as I originally stated) that $\Lambda_r > 1$. In other words, 
$RR = \{ \Lambda_r > 1\} $.

However, if $X  \sim Uniform(0, \theta)$ distributed random variable then under $H_0$ it is impossible for the maximum $X_{(n)}$ to be greater than $\theta_0$ and so it is impossible for $\Lambda_r > 1$, since under the null $X  \sim Uniform(0, \theta_0)$ and thus $Pr[ X_{(n)} > \theta_0 | \theta = \theta_0] = 0 $ .

Thus,

$Pr[reject \ H_0 | H_0 \ is \ true] = Pr[\ \Lambda_r > 1\ | \theta = \theta_0] = Pr[X_{(n)} > \theta_0 | \theta = \theta_0] =  0.$

Thus, it follows that if we observe a maximum value that is greater than $\theta_0$ that the null hypothesis cannot be true (ie. the alternative hypothesis must be true), since under the null hypothesis the probability of observing a maximum value greater than $\theta_0$ is zero, regardless of $\alpha$.

Comment: A good question requires some time to create so you can engage with the potential posters who will not open an unknown document link - so please take a look at [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Unless there is a specific rush?

Comment: Please note that I have transcribed the entire document into MathJax.  This was a substantial amount of text and I did this as quickly as possible, so you are **strongly** advised to check the revision for accuracy.

Comment: I apologize for not learning mathjax. There is no specific rush, but it was a comfort thing. I don't quite understand how a Google drive document can be malicious, but I am sorry if this isn't a well put together question. Also, thanks heropup. The transcription is indeed accurate to what I was trying to convey.

Comment: @aranglol It is a matter of courtesy:  people are taking the time to read and potentially answer your question.  Put yourself in the place of such a person:  would **you** want to take the time to click the link and read the document just to see if you **could** answer it, and if so, then take the time to compose an answer by switching back and forth between browser tabs?

Comment: The fact that I went through and took the time to  **transcribe your question for you** should not be interpreted as a sign that members of this site will do this sort of work for you.  I only did it because you are new and your document demonstrated significant effort to solve your problem.  If you wish to benefit from this community, you would do well to learn how to use the mathematical formatting tools provided.

Comment: I did not intend to give off the impression that I would expect this out of all of my posts, or that I don't appreciate other people's time, but I thought the original accusation was due to the unknown document potentially being malicious. I also didn't feel that it would be that big of a hit to workflow since I thought one could open up two windows and split their desktop screen, but it is clear I was mistaken. Believe me, I am grateful for this community and if I ask another question in the future I will take note and learn the formatting tools. Forgive me if I came off passive aggressive.

Comment: It is clear that I should have been more appreciative and courteous towards those who are helping me, so I apologize.